# Логика работы оператора in в строках содержащих скобочную последовательность: "(), {}, []"

Tags: python, строки, while, replace, set

Столкнулся с задачей для новичков "Скобочная последовательность", в которой нужно определить, является ли входная строка допустимой. Задачу решил, но с помощью кода, который нашёл в итнернете!

```py
def is_valid(text: str) -> bool:
    while '()' in text or '[]' in text or '{}' in text:
        text = text.replace('()', '')
        text = text.replace('[]', '')
        text = text.replace('{}', '')
    return not text
```

Так вот чём вопрос: почему при таком расположении скобок (`text = "({}){[}]")` в строке функция выдаёт False? Ведь тут открывающие скобки равны по количеству закрывающим?
Каким образом происходит проверка правильной последовательности скобок и замена на пустое значение при такой конструкции?
В документации ничего об этом не нашёл(

Comment: Почему? Потому что последовательность очевидно неправильная. `)(` тоже неправильная, хотя количество совпадает.

Comment: Ищется и заменяется строка в `in` и `replace` целиком, а не отдельные её символы. В подстроке `{[}]` просто нет тех последовательностей, которые ищутся и заменяются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условие в цикле проверяет на вхождение () - False, [] - False, {} -True заменяет {} на ''. Получаем "(){[}]". второй заход () - True, [] - False, {} - False. Заменяет (). Получаем "{[}]". () - False, [] - False, {} - False Цикл закончен. В переменной осталась строка "{[}]". выводится False т.к. выражение  "{[}]" - это не строка является ложным.

Comment: Это всё вроде и так понятно из кода.

Comment: Человек спрашивает, значит ему не понятно, а вот я у тебя не спрашивал ничего.

Comment: @Voloading, спасибо! Очень доходчиво объяснил. Всё понятно)